# metabox upload file

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have a custom meta filed with upload file functionality but the problem is I can't get the fileurl button value when hit "insert into Post" below are my jQuery code

```
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) 

    {
        dlink = jQuery('button.urlfile',html).attr('title');
        jQuery('#download_link').val(dlink);
        tb_remove();
    }


    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=1&amp;type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
```

Comment: If you are uploading a file and not an image, it might be good to change "&amp;type=image" to "&amp;type=file" as a starting place.

Comment: See [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/display-media-uploader-in-own-plugin-on-wordpress-3-5/81482#81482), hints and source examples to the media uploader in wp 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Again. If you are using file upload, it is different than image upload. To get a FILE url, use: $(html).attr('href');

File upload:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html){
    var file_url = $(html).attr('href');

    // Do something with those variables

    tb_remove();
};
```

Image upload:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html){
    var file_url = $('img', html).attr('src'),
        classes  = $('img', html).attr('class'),
        id       = classes.replace(/(.*?)wp-image-/, '');

    // Do something with those variables

    tb_remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html){
    dlink = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#download_link').val(dlink);
    tb_remove();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I tried it out before and doesnt work since I upload is file not image :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <label style="float:left; margin: 5px 5px 0 0;">Image 4:</label>
    <input type="text" id="image_4" name="image_4" value="" style="width: 550px; float:left; margin:0 5px;"/>
    <input id="_btn" class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image4_id" id="image4_id" value="<?php echo $image_id4; ?>" />
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var formfield;
    var id;
    jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function () {
        jQuery('html').addClass('Image');
        formfield = jQuery(this).prev().attr('name');
        id = jQuery(this).next().attr('name');

        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });
    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
    window.send_to_editor = function (html) {
        if (formfield) {
            fileurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
            jQuery('#' + formfield).val(fileurl);

            imgclass = jQuery('img', html).attr('class');
            imgid = parseInt(imgclass.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
            jQuery('#' + id).val(imgid);

            tb_remove();
            jQuery('html').removeClass('Image');
        } else {
            window.original_send_to_editor(html);
        }
    };
});
</script>
```