# Display Media Uploader in Own Plugin on Wordpress 3.5

Tags: jquery, media

I have little problem with Media Uploader in new WordPress 3.5. I created own plugin which is upload the picture. I'm using this code JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var file_frame;

    jQuery('.button-secondary').live('click', function( event ){

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( file_frame ) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media(
            {
                title: 'Select File',
                button: {
                    text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' )
                },
                multiple: false
            }
        );

        file_frame.on('select', function() {
            attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            jQuery('#IMGsrc').val(attachment.url);
        });

        file_frame.open();
    });
</script>
```

The code works fine, but unfortunately forms appears incomplete. When I select any picture doesn't show me 'Attachment Display Settings' on right side. I don't know why. I try add options to media:

```
displaySettings: true,
displayUserSettings: true
```

But it also doesn't work.

Comment: are you calling `wp_enqueue_media();` ?

Answer (score 6):

**Only Uploader**

below a example code, works only on post edit page. If you will use also on other page, then include the function `wp_enqueue_media()`, see the next headline.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var _custom_media = true,
      _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

  $('.stag-metabox-table .button').click(function(e) {

    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    var button = $(this);
    var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');

    _custom_media = true;
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {

      if ( _custom_media ) {
        $("#"+id).val(attachment.url);
      } else {
        return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
      };

    }

    wp.media.editor.open(button);

    return false;
  });

  $('.add_media').on('click', function() {
    _custom_media = false;
  });

});
```

**Short explanation of Media Manager**

1. At first include the relevant scripts, use the core function: `wp_enqueue_media();`
   The function set up all the relevant settings, localizes menu text, and loads in all the appropriate javascript files.

   You can add custom script via `wp_enqueue_script()`.

   ```
   // Also adds a check to make sure `wp_enqueue_media` has only been called once.
   // @see: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22843
   if ( ! did_action( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) )
       wp_enqueue_media();
   ```

   Add also a default script for custom header: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-header' );`
   This creates an image selection frame, and ties it to an interface element, for example a button or link. It then calls a url or our choice with the selected image id. This is the same script that is used when selecting theme custom header images.
2. Add the button to media manager:

   ```
   <?php
   $modal_update_href = esc_url( add_query_arg( array(
       'page'     => 'my_media_manager',
       '_wpnonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'my_media_manager_options' ),
   ), admin_url( 'upload.php' ) ) );
   ?>

   <p>
   <a id="choose-from-library-link" href="#"
       data-update-link="<?php echo esc_attr( $modal_update_href ); ?>"
       data-choose="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Choose a Default Image' ); ?>"
       data-update="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Set as default image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Set default image' ); ?>
   </a> |
   </p>
   ```
3. Define Action Function
   last, you need to add in some code for processing the image id that we will pass to the data-update-link url.

   ```
   // Add to the top of our data-update-link page
   if ( isset($_REQUEST['file']) ) { 
       check_admin_referer( 'my_media_manager_options' );

           // Process and save the image id
       $options = get_option( 'my_media_manager_options', TRUE );
       $options['default_image'] = absint( $_REQUEST['file'] );
       update_option( 'my_media_manager_options', $options );
   }
   ```

**Sources and hints:**

- http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/
- http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/
- https://github.com/AgencyPMG/PMG-WP-Core/commit/6a5a1ee818b9a8f03bf7df6e9f16b118f999355c
- Filter and Action Hooks: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22186#comment:46

Comment: What would the 'page' attribute be for an admin page, say Widgets.php?

Comment: Use the [Current Admin Info](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) plugin and you see this string, also all hooks, thee can use about this page. In your example is it `widgets.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I have put a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin/23701719#23701719) in the stackoverflow.com site as well and that would be help.

I'm using this method to use media uploader into my custom plugin.May be this would be help.

in the **main theme file(index.php)** add these.

```
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); // call to media files in wp
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload'); 


// load script to admin
function wpss_admin_js() {
     $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
     $url = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/js/admin_script.js';
     echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='$url'></script>"; 
}
 add_action('admin_head', 'wpss_admin_js');
```

In the **admin_script.js** file,

```
jQuery('#wpss_upload_image_button').click(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#wpss_upload_image').attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#wpss_upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();

 jQuery('#wpss_upload_image_thumb').html("<img height='65' src='"+imgurl+"'/>");
}
```

**admin file(admin_settings.php),**

```
<div id="wpss_upload_image_thumb" class="wpss-file">
    <?php if(isset($record->security_image) && $record->security_image !='') { ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $record->security_image;?>"  width="65"/><?php } else {    echo $defaultImage; } ?>
</div>
<input id="wpss_upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="wpss_upload_image" value="" class="wpss_text wpss-file" />
<input id="wpss_upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" class="wpss-filebtn" />
```

More details [in my blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin/23701719#23701719)

More info
http://webexplorar.com/how-to-use-media-uploader-in-wordpress-custom-plugin/

Comment: Please transfer that answer to your answer here. If that link gets removed, your answer here will be useless.

Comment: I think the thickbox now at this time is so old.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code for media uploader .
you got link in jquery response.

```
<label for="upload_image">
    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
    <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
</label>

<?php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: true
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            console.log(custom_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON());
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
    </script>
```