# Widget plugin and input file

Tags: plugin-development, input

I am writing a widget plugin; and I want to insert an input tag:`<input type="file">` to browse for a pattern in my widget plugin admin panel; but I have problem to save its value(address of the pattern).
It seems that `<input type="file">` doesn't work in widget plugins. Is it correct? Are there any other ways to browse a file from the admin panel?

here is the input file code in the widget form function:

```
<fieldset id="customize">
 <label>Browse pattern:</label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" size="15" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('menupattern'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('menupattern'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['menupattern']; ?>" /> 
</fieldset>
```

@s_ha_dum, I have been read the link about `enctype` ; but it wasn't helpful.
please note that in the widget plugins I have to send data by the widget `form( $instance )` function, and I want to let the user to select a photo from the webserver; not to upload it!

Comment: I don't see why a file input wouldn't work, if you are properly handling form submission. can't really help you any further without seeing some code.

Comment: Post your code please. Does your form have an  `enctype`?

Comment: here is the section of the input file code in the widget settings form:
`<fieldset id="customize">

        <p>
        <label>Browse pattern:</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" size="15" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('menupattern'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('menupattern'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['menupattern']; ?>" />     
        </p>
  
</fieldset>
`
@s_ha_dum, what should I do about `enctype`?
can you explain more or link to relative pages?

Comment: [Edit] your question with the additional information. Code is nearly unreadable in the comments. Enctype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: a file input is for uploading files *from a user's local machine*, not a web server. see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/display-media-uploader-in-own-plugin-on-wordpress-3-5) about integrating the media window with a plugin.

Comment: @Milo,I couldn't understand how to plain the code of the link(which you have offered to me) in a widget plugin. In general; I can handle my wish by the  `$_GET["input_name"]` ;but for a widget plugin it's different because of its rules!
any more applicable ways?! :|

Comment: I don't understand what "rules" you're talking about.

Comment: I'm talking about each function of the widget plugin codes,see the default usage section:http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: I know how a widget works, it's just not clear what your issue with it is. again, if you're providing a way for users to select images on a server, an input field is most certainly the wrong type of field.

Comment: OK, can you guide me more to find a better way? as I wrote before, "I couldn't understand how to plain the code of the link(which you have offered to me)"

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'post_edit_form_tag');
function post_edit_form_tag() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
```

Add the above code in your active theme's `functions.php` file.

Then `print_r($_file)` will display the file array.

Comment: nope, doesn't affect widget form, only edit post form (WP 4.3)