# How can I use multi Media Uploader in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, media-library

I try to add the multi uploading options in a WordPress plugin. I repeated this code in the plugin (two times) only changing the ID.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
        formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
        jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    };
});
</script>
<input 
    id="upload_image" 
    style=" margin-left:303px;" 
    type="text" 
    size="36" 
    name="upload_image_template" 
    value="<?php echo get_option('upload_image_template'); ?>" />
<input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Browse" />
```

Whenever I try to upload a image that media frame comes and the uploading process are did successfully. But *Insert Into Post* fetch the correct url but pasted in different input box.
For example:

```
1) [text box1] [browse Button]
2) [text box2] [browse button]
```

When I upload image with Text Box One that `[insert post]` that image path is shown in `[text box 2]`
I am Not Sure Whether the Problem is mine or that script didn't support multi file upload option.

Comment: Use the new way to do this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/display-media-uploader-in-own-plugin-on-wordpress-3-5

Comment: This plugin does exactly what you need http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/