# ThickBox replacement

Tags: thickbox, media-modal

I'm searching, unsuccessfully unfortunately, for a ThickBox replacement used in Media Uploader.

Any search fails on how to leverage Media Uploader and nothing about a script used for modal windows.

Can somebody help me? Is there a way to use the same modal as Media Uploader is using, but to put custom content in it like it was possible with ThickBox?

Comment: Is this for use on the front end or backend?

Comment: Backend. I was trying to use lightbox like standard media uploader. I found out that it is not thickbox replacement but modal especialy made just for media uploader and it is not reusable in the way Thickbox is. I have used thickbox

Comment: I think they use backbone This would be the js https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/media-views.js. For my plugins I used Colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: You'll want to look at the underscore-templates, and how they interact with wp-views and wp.media objects. Unfortunately it's not well documented.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have integrated the new media uploader in a plugin which allows the admin to select or upload media from the standard media dialog instead of having to copy/paste URLs, and it seems to work well.

I posted an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129571/how-to-let-a-user-select-a-media-from-the-media-library/165499#165499) that might be what you're looking for.

Tom McFarlin has a tuts+ series [in the works](https://tommcfarlin.com/working-wordpress-media-uploader/) as of last month.

Other links that may help:

- [How to use WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader in Theme Options](https://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/)
- [Display Media Uploader in Own Plugin on Wordpress 3.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78547/display-media-uploader-in-own-plugin-on-wordpress-3-5)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you want to use a popup that has contents other than Media Uploader. To achieve this follow these steps:

1. Add this code to include the thickbox script.

   ```
   <?php
   add_action('init', 'init_theme_method');
   function init_theme_method() {
   add_thickbox();
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Add class='thickbox' to any clickable element that will show the popup.

   ```
   <input alt="#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=examplePopup1" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox" type="button" value="Show Thickbox Example Pop-up 1" />
   ```
3. Notice in the last code there is inlineId parameter. This will be the code to be displayed inside popup box.

   ```
      <div id="examplePopup1" style="display:none">
       <h2>Example Pop-up Window 1</h2>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed laoreet est. Etiam nec nibh aliquam leo maximus hendrerit. Aliquam velit erat, pretium eget faucibus ut, ullamcorper in sapien. Nulla dignissim turpis et pharetra vestibulum. Nulla et mattis eros. Integer consequat, odio sed gravida bibendum, dui purus viverra nisl, nec fringilla ante nibh non lorem. Morbi at tristique diam. Mauris et aliquam tellus, vehicula dapibus odio. Maecenas vulputate turpis ac orci fringilla, id cursus augue mollis. Aliquam sit amet ligula tellus.


       <strong>Just click outside the pop-up to close it.</strong>
       </div>
   ```

I hope this helps

Source: [Create Pop-up Windows in Your WordPress Blog with Thickbox](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/create-pop-up-windows-in-your-wordpress-blog-with-thickbox)

Comment: I just realized that this is an old question but it was on the top of the list for the unanswered questions list.